# discord.js Sending Custom Messsage and Bot Mirrors message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am newer to coding Discord.js and Im trying to figure this out. This specific command should repeat what the user said and then delete the user message.

For example: !gc Hello World!

Bot responses: Hello World!

Bot Deletes user command and keeps the Bot message.

```
bot.on('message', message => {
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

message.channel.send(message)
message.delete('message')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... in order to get the message content, you should use `Message.content`. Problem is, this will contain all the content, including prefix and command name so you'll have to splice it out.

To delete the message you don't need to pass anything as a parameter. Although you can pass a timer if you don't want to delete the message instantly. For example `Message.delete(1000)` will delay the message deletion for 1 second.

Hard coding the command you could do it like this:

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}gc`)) {
    // Substring the message so you can rip off the prefix and command name
    let msg = message.content;
    msg = msg.substring(prefix.length + 3, msg.length);

    message.channel.send(msg);
    message.delete();
  }
});
```

**Notice that this is a suggestion to work as an explanation and isn't a good way to code commands.**

You can learn how to create a proper bot and manage the project directory [here](https://discordjs.guide/).
If you want to learn specifically command handling you can go directly to [here](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/).